# How to remove a whitespace character and insert a string in its place

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to take a string such as `Hello World this is Bob` and have it formatted to

`:h: :e: :l: :l: :o: | :w: :o: :r: :l: :d: | :t: :h: :i: :s: | :i: :s: | :b: :o: :b:`

This is where I'm having the issue:

```rb
text = text.scan(/\s/).join(' | ')
```

```rb
def to_clipboard(text)
  string = text.to_s
  IO.popen('pbcopy', 'w') {|t| t << text}
  string
end
#########################################
print "Enter message: "

text = gets.downcase.chomp!
# text = text.scan(/\s/).join(' | ')
formatted = text.scan(/\S[A-Za-z]{0,0}/).join(': :')

formatted.insert(0,':')
formatted[formatted.size, 0] = ':'

# verify expected format
puts formatted

to_clipboard(formatted)
```

Comment: What about `text.gsub(/\s+|(\S)/) { |m| m == $~[1] ? ":#{$~[1].downcase}: " : ' | ' }.strip`?

Comment: `text.chars.map { |m| m == ' ' ? '|' : ":#{m}:" }.join(' ')` would work.

Comment: @Stefan, `each_char`? :-)

Comment: m_antis, regarding your comment below concerning @Wiktor's regex, it just needs a trivial tweak: changing `' | '` to `'| '`. Had you just mentioned that in a comment he would have provided the adjustment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def bannerize(str)
  str.downcase.gsub(/./) do |c|
    if c == ' '
      "| "
    else
      ":#{c}: "
    end
  end.rstrip
end
```

```
bannerize("Hello this is Mugsy")
  #=> ":h: :e: :l: :l: :o: | :t: :h: :i: :s: | :i: :s: | :m: :u: :g: :s: :y:"
```

Alternatively,

```
def bannerize(str)
  h = Hash.new { |_,k| ":#{k}: " }.tap { |h| h[' '] = "| " }
  str.downcase.gsub(/./,h).rstrip
end
```

This uses the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that creates an empty hash `h` with a *default proc*, after which the key-value pair `' '=>" "` is added to the hash so that it becomes `{ ' '=>" " }`. The default proc causes `h[k]` to return `":#{k}: "` if it does not have a key `k`; that is, if `k` is anything other than a space.

The form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that employs a hash for making substitutions is then used with this hash `h`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to split by space, make a replacement in each word and then combine results:

```
words = text.split(/\s/)
words.map {|s| s.gsub(/(.)/, ':\1: ')}
formatted = words.join('| ')
```

Comment: I see where you're coming from but that didn't make one difference

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

```
text = 'Hello World this is Bob'
p text.strip.gsub(/\s+|(\S)/) { |m| m == $~[1] ? ":#{$~[1].downcase}: " : '| ' }.rstrip
## => ":h: :e: :l: :l: :o: | :w: :o: :r: :l: :d: | :t: :h: :i: :s: | :i: :s: | :b: :o: :b:"
```

See the [Ruby demo online](https://ideone.com/Xh9WbU).

**NOTES**:

- The string is first stripped from leading/trailing whitespace in order not to add pipe at the start.
- `gsub(/\s+|(\S)/) { |m| m == $~[1] ? ":#{$~[1].downcase}: " : '| ' }` does the main job within one regex replace pass:

  - `/\s+|(\S)/` - matches 1+ whitespaces, or matches and captures into Group 1 any single non-whitespace character
  - The replacement is a block where `m` represents the match value. If the match value is equal Group 1 value (`m == $~[1] ?`) then the replacement is `:`, then Group 1 value in lower case (`#{$~[1].downcase}`), and then `:` , else, the replacement is `|` .
- Since there may be a trailing space after `gsub`, the string is `rstrip`ped.